# EF 6 Multiple Context to the same Database(table/entitie separation)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-6, unit-of-work

For my project i need to break the Database to multiple Context for modulation separation, example:

- DataContext1: Car, Person, Color.(Geral Module)
- DataContext2: BankAccount, Money, Income.(Financial Module)

And on the code i will need to have a unit of work that combine the two for the same transaction code.

```
public class MyClass(IUserRepository userRepository, IBankRepository bankRepository, IUnityOfWork uow)
{
  // uow start transaction
  // IUserRepository is inside ContextA
  // IBankRepository is inside ContextB
  // uow end transaction(Commit)
}
```

Referring to the EF 6.+

- this separation is OK?, DataContext Support it?
- It can be a massive problem on the future for managing them?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you will have is that any type/table in context cannot be repeated in the other without massive complication. For example, if a table in the UserContext is related to a table in the BankAccount context then you cannot have that relationship in your models because then you would have the same table - and thus type - defined in two places. I've never done this, but I can't see it ending anywhere good.

If you really really need to split your context into two or more, one approach might be to have one model which contains everything, plus a class which will wrap the context for each subsystem, which only exposes the types required by that subsystem. This is sort of the Adaptor or Mediator pattern.